# How to add my own columns to Jenkin's Dashboard

Tags: jenkins

I want to add my custom columns, and I also want to add some popups on those columns in Jenkins dashboard.

How does one add new columns, which are not present in job's configuration page?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [Jenkins Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) to add the layout of your choice. The page says:

> The dashboard view comes with a number of portlets that you can configure your view with

so you can add top, bottom, or column portlets as you seee fit.

Comment: I want to change the table contents and table headers of dashboard. I don't want to add any additional portlets in jenkins dashboard

Comment: What content do you want in the tables?

Comment: I need to add columns for everyday build with the date header. and I need to get a popup, which shows number of builds and build details.

Comment: # Service Name                    08/07/2019  08/06/2019  08/05/2019  08/04/2019                                                                                     
1 xyz       
2 Affiliation_Reporting   success      Fail       success     success

Comment: Like the above table.

Answer (score 0):

I wish that was possible, but it seems there's nothing yet. However, I found a decent workaround: you can select column 'Project Description'. Of course, in the project description you can write anything. That includes html code, so for example, you can use that to include links in your dashboard.